# Хеширование файлов в Python. SHA3 - 256

Tags: python, кодировка, хеширование

Есть скрипт на Python, который хеширует файлы из папки. Эти файлы имеют расширение **.data**
Скрипт вроде работает, **первую строку выдаёт правильно**, но **последующие строки сбиваются** и результат оказывается неверным. Что нужно сделать, чтобы скрипт не сбивался и выдавал правильный результат хеширования?

```
import os
import hashlib

for f in os.scandir('E:/task2'):
    if f.is_file() and f.path.split('.')[-1].lower() == 'data':
        with open(f.path, 'rb') as datafile:
            red = datafile.read()
            while len(red)>0:
                file_hash = hashlib.sha3_256()
                file_hash.update(red)
                red = datafile.read()
    print(file_hash.hexdigest())
```

Вывод: a2441864092c02e573e14285f57ea6cb4c7f9c9dd6f4e24c10b168c10c1e9fed - **правильный вывод**

```
   db4a62bad55c236ac748485eb8687dee25f9af32170ab571ac8b9fa19c51b9bb - должно быть 32c83dca21d18562e84ae5f59e187b34849f9608d2a3b48d7eb78c62e2b76b2f
   
   129b00d6f9923d8ccdae7bac828f5f5c11379931352fd57c7ba1a08e017dbb00 - должно быть a3489252b57c91cb4cf70100fcde332972f2871afa73abf787dea6b38a8b877d
   
   182fcb235d402bb8b04ea8a6e2ff9f906eb1b5e50e2bb3da1cc1a270a21516aa - должно быть 59eee7dd0eb44df88bd53ec135632113e2539f8322ba039737a2a7f01eb0b79b
```

и тд. Всего 256 строк

Comment: А почему вы `file_hash = hashlib.sha3_256()` делаете внутри цикла чтения файла, а не перед ним. Фактически вы начинаете считать хеш заново для каждого читаемого блока

Comment: Вынес по вашему совету file_hash = hashlib.sha3_256() за пределы цикла, но всё равно правильной остаётся только первая строка, значения поменялись, но до сих пор не то

Comment: Прошу прощение за свою невнимательность, не посмотрел что при выводе файлы сортируются по имени, в итоге алгоритм менял файлы местами, так всё работает отлично, спасибо:)